# Visual Studio 2010 - CTRL-F - accidentally removed "You've reached end of solution" dialog box

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search through my solution. I reached the end of the solution and a dialog box appeared saying that I had reached the end of my solution. There is a checked checkbox in this dialog box where the user can decide whether or not he or she wants this dialog box to appear.

In my haste, I accidentally unchecked the checked box and clicked okay. How can I make this dialog box appear again?

Comment: Have you tried Tools->Options->Environment->Find and Replace and put mark on 'Display informational messages' and 'Display warning messages'?

Comment: I have - I believe they are checked by default and they are still checked now.

Comment: Ah that was it - the first box was shadowed, so I "un-shadowed" it and selected it again and now it is checked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try putting marks on 'Display informational messages' and 'Display warning messages' and make sure the check boxes are not shadowed like the below image.

[image]